# How do I configure the Gnome Do Microblogging plugin for Twitter?

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, twitter, gnome-do

I'm having trouble configuring the Microblogging plugin for Gnome Do to use my Twitter account. I'm able to sign into Twitter.com without any problem, but the same login credential result in an error saying, "Account authentication failed!" when used in Microblogging plugin. My username consists only of letters, and my password has both letters and numbers. What am I doing wrong?

I'm a Ubuntu 10.04 user.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the [Microblogging plugin](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Talk:Microblogging_Plugin) for Gnome Do was broken when Twitter updated their authentication to OAuth.